# Find the other 2 interior angles of pentagon inscribed in a circle given 3 angles.

Tags: geometry, circles

[image: Relevant diagram]

Given a pentagon $ABCDE$ inscribed in a circle with centre $O$. Three of the interior angles are $95^°$, $130^°$ and $138^°$. Find angle $x$ and $y$.

I'm quite sure that $x$ and $y$ can be found as the other three angles are fixed, so $x$ and $y$ should also be fixed by the circle arc.

Comment: The sum of the interior angles of a polygon with $n$ sides is $180^\circ \cdot(n-2)$. Does that help?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This question contains an error as $x$ and $y$ are not fixed. There are many ways to draw the pentagon with 3 same angles.

Comment: -1 But not so many ways to draw a cyclic pentagon.

Comment: No $x$ and $y$ are not fixed. At first I thought they are fixed too. But they are not. You can try to draw out and you will see.

Comment: $x+y$ remains constant but values of $x$ and $y$ vary.

Comment: Ok - I concede the point. Can;t see a way of getting further than $x+y=177$. Though min(x) appears to be about 50, max(x) about 92.

Answer (score -1):

answer for x is 74 and y is 103

Comment: Can you explain *why* this is the correct answer?